# Can MongoDB resolve empty string as property name?

Tags: mongodb

Knows somebody, how to query from MongoDB value from this (JSON valid, pretty printed) object:

```
var a = JSON.parse(`
{
    "vnut_okraj_podmienky": {
        "": {
            "standart_podmienky": {
                "type": "radio",
                "value": "on"
            },
            "nestand_teplota": {
                "type": "number",
                "value": "24"
            },
            "nestand_vlhkost": {
                "type": "number",
                "value": "70"
            }
        }
    }
}
`
```

In browser console I can obtain value (=24) of:

```
a.vnut_okraj_podmienky[""].nestand_teplota.value
```

but mongosh returns [] on this (db name irrelevant):

```
db.isover_projects.distinct("vnut_okraj_podmienky.''.nestand_teplota.value")
```

and error **MongoServerError: FieldPath field names may not be empty strings.**
on:

```
db.isover_projects.distinct("vnut_okraj_podmienky..nestand_teplota.value")
```

Comment: Using an empty string as a key seems like you're asking for trouble. Even if this is allowed, I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Yes, I agree, but the troubles come from about 2000 foreign JSON files, which I have to search

Answer (score 2):

The MongoDB server stores data in BSON.

According the specification at https://bsonspec.org/spec.html a field name must be

> Zero or more modified UTF-8 encoded characters followed by '\x00'. The (byte*) MUST NOT contain '\x00', hence it is not full UTF-8.

So it technically can store the empty string as a field name.

This works in simple queries as well:

```
>db.collection.find({"":{a:1}})
[ { _id: ObjectId("616c4783e3be8ecf36d5e932"), '': { a: 1 } } ]
```

This also works dotted notation:

```
>db.collection.find({".a":1})
[ { _id: ObjectId("616c4783e3be8ecf36d5e932"), '': { a: 1 } } ]
```

However, that does not work if you try to use that empty field name with update, projection, or aggregation operators:

```
>db.collection.aggregate([{$match:{".a":1}},{$set:{".b":2}}])
MongoError: Invalid $set :: caused by :: FieldPath field names may not be empty strings.
```

So while it is technically permitted to store a document with a field whose name is the empty string, not all operations are support on such fields.

Comment: So, I must ask mongodb developers to improve code :-)

Comment: ran into an issue where we have empty string as a key name in MongoDB and next to impossible to filter it out, without writing a script :'(